# How to write a function which should run the callback once every 'wait' milliseconds upto 'limit' miliseconds and then stop

Tags: javascript

Write a function called `limitedInterval` that accepts as arguments in this order:-

- callback function
- wait time in milliseconds
- limit time in milliseconds.

`limitedInterval` should run the callback once every `wait` milliseconds, up to `limit` milliseconds, and then stop.

Here's what I have tried to do:

```
function limitedInterval(callback, wait, limit){
    setTimeout(callback, wait);  
}
var wait = 100;
var limit = 550;
function callback(){
  console.log("Repeating Callback");
}
// should log 'repeating' once per 100 ms, five times.
limitedInterval(() => console.log('repeating'), wait, limit);
```

I am not able to understand how to set limit on setTimeout so that function should log 'repeating' once per 100 ms, five times

Comment: Post your attempts here.

Comment: Looks like homework problem to me.

Comment: Sorry, now I have added the attempts that I have made to solve the problem. Look the question again.

Comment: I just want to understand how to set the limit so that callback runs once per 100ms for five times.

Comment: You should have sequential calls to *setTimeout* and keep track of the elapsed time. When the aggregate is more than limit, don't call it again.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like following:

```
const TEMPO = 100;
const MAX = 500;
let count = 0;
const id = setInterval(() => {
  console.log('x');
  if (count > MAX) {
    clearInterval(id);
  }
  count += TEMPO;
}, TEMPO);
```

1. Initialize the constants and `count` to provide limitation
2. Run interval incrementing `count` per each iteration
3. Break interval when count is out of `MAX` value

Comment: The OP doesn't want a count, but an elapsed time.

Comment: @RobG I'm counting milliseconds in this sample, so it could be treated as elapsed time. By the way, I posted [another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54103809/3211932) with no count, maybe you will like it more.

Comment: Yes, I like the other one more. The elapsed time is rarely the sum of the waits. But you shouldn't answer where the OP has made no attempt at their own code.

Answer (score 1):

An approach based on both `setInterval` and `setTimeout` javascript-timer methods:

```
const TEMPO = 100;
const MAX = 500;
const id = setInterval(() => {
  console.log('x');
}, TEMPO);
setTimeout(() => clearInterval(id), MAX);
```

1. Initialize the constants
2. Run interval with given `TEMPO`
3. Run timeout with `MAX` delay to break interval

Answer (score 1):

```js
// PROMT: run <cb> every <wait> miliseconds, not exceeding <limit>:

function limitedInterval(callback, waitTime, timeLimit) {
  let timer = waitTime; // keep track of time passed; the setInterval method starts after an initial delay of waitTime
  
  const ID = setInterval(() => {    // prepend the setInterval method by saving/naming this intance (i.e., set the id [which is automatically assigned by JavaScript] to a variable so you can refer to this setInterval method in line 10)
    callback();                             // (1) call the function
    timer += waitTime;              // (2) update timer
    if (timer > timeLimit) {    // (3.1) continue function if timeLimit is not exceeded
      clearInterval(ID);            // (3.2) end the setInterval method (when condition is met)
    };
  }, waitTime);
  
}


limitedInterval( () => console.log('repeating'), 100, 550 ); // should log 'repeating' once per 100 ms, five times.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to increment time before invoking the callback, otherwise you will call it one too many times.

```
const limitedInterval = (callback, wait, limit) => {
  let time = 0; 

  const handleTime = () => {
    time += wait; // increment time before checking limit & invoking callback
    if (time < limit) {
      callback();
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }

  const interval = setInterval(handleTime, wait);
}
```